# different call using the same channel

Tags: go, channel

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
$ go version 1.13.1
```

#### Does this issue reproduce with the latest release?

I'm not sure.

#### What operating system and processor architecture are you using (`go env`)?

```
$ go env
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/data/xieyixin/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/data/xieyixin/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/data/xieyixin/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="http://10.0.12.201:8989/"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/data/xieyixin/hxagent/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build474907248=/tmp/go-build"
```

#### What did you do?

**I write a function to do exec command, and control timeout cases on my own.**
**And I test it like this**

```
package utils

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func ExecCommand(command string, timeout time.Duration) (string, error) {
    log.Printf("command:%v, timeout:%v", command, timeout)
    var (
        cmd    *exec.Cmd
        stdout bytes.Buffer
        stderr bytes.Buffer
        result string
        err    error
        //timeouterr error
    )
    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer cancelFn()

    cmd = exec.Command("bash", "-c", "--", command)
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}

    var waitDone = make(chan struct{})
    defer func() {
        log.Printf("waitDone addr:%v\n", &waitDone)
        log.Printf("close waitdone channel\n")
        close(waitDone)
    }()
    go func() {
        err = cmd.Run()
        log.Printf("waitDone addr:%v\n", &waitDone)
        waitDone <- struct{}{}
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Printf("timeout to kill process, %v", cmd.Process.Pid)
        syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
        result = convertStr(stdout)
        err = ctx.Err()
    case <-waitDone:
        if err != nil {
            result = convertStr(stderr)
        } else {
            result = convertStr(stdout)
        }
    }

    log.Printf("result:%v,err:%v", result, err)

    return result, err
}

func convertStr(buffer bytes.Buffer) string {
    data := buffer.String()
    return data
}
```

```
package utils

import (
    "context"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestExecCommand(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        command string
        timeout time.Duration
        wantErr string
        want    string
    }{
        {
            command: "sleep 10",
            timeout: time.Second * 5,
            wantErr: context.DeadlineExceeded.Error(),
        },
        {
            command: "watch -n 1 date +%s",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
            wantErr: context.DeadlineExceeded.Error(),
            want:    "timeout, but still have result.",
        },
        {
            command: "hostname",
            timeout: time.Second * 5,
            wantErr: "",
            want:    "anything result would be fine.",
        },
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        // got panic here. 
        // send on closed channel.
        got, gotErr := ExecCommand(tt.command, tt.timeout)
        if gotErr == nil {
            if tt.wantErr == "" {
                t.Logf("succeed")
            } else {
                t.Errorf("failed case: %+v, got:%v, gotErr:%v\n", tt, got, gotErr)
            }
        } else if gotErr.Error() == tt.wantErr {
            t.Logf("succeed")
        } else {
            t.Errorf("failed case: %+v, got:%v, gotErr:%v\n", tt, got, gotErr)
        }

    }
}
```

#### What did you expect to see?

test ok.

#### What did you see instead?

panic: send on closed channel.

edit1 : the reason why I controls context on my own
[https://medium.com/@felixge/killing-a-child-process-and-all-of-its-children-in-go-54079af94773]

edit2 : More confusion here.

it seems a little bit clear to me. but i still got some question.
[https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=11462:11489#L440],

```
if c.ctx != nil {
        c.waitDone = make(chan struct{}) // here
        go func() {
            select {
            case <-c.ctx.Done():
                c.Process.Kill()
            case <-c.waitDone: // and here
            }
        }()
    }
```

as you can see, it's similar to @Cerise Limón 's code. why should we write this channel. is it neccessary?

Comment: Consider the scenario where the context times out before the command completes.  ExecCommand can execute the deferred call to close the channel before the Run goroutine sends to the channel. Consider using [exec.CommandContext](https://godoc.org/os/exec#CommandContext).

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks, I knew that, I chose to cancel process because the issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23019.

Comment: Because `close(waitDone)` is called after any goroutine receives on the channel, the call is not needed. To prevent the goroutine from hanging after context completion, the application should close the channel after `err = cmd.Run()` returns or create the channel with capacity 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [exec.CommandContext](https://godoc.org/os/exec#CommandContext) instead of writing this code on your own.

In the scenario where the context times out before the command completes, the `ExecCommand` function can close the channel before the Run goroutine sends to the channel. This causes the panic.

Because the application does not receive on `waitDone` after `close(waitDone)` is executed, there's no point in closing the channel.

Another issue is exposed if the code to close the channel is removed. Because `waitDone` is an unbuffered channel, the Run goroutine will block forever on send to `waitDone` in the timeout scenario.

The call to `cmd.Run()` starts a goroutine to copy data to `stdout` and `stderr`. There's no guarantee that these goroutines are done executing before `ExecCommand` calls `convertStr(stdout)` or `convertStr(stderr)`.

Here's one fix for all of this:

```
func ExecCommand(command string, timeout time.Duration) (string, error) {
    log.Printf("command:%v, timeout:%v", command, timeout)
    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    defer cancelFn()

    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer

    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "--", command)
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
            log.Printf("timeout to kill process, %v", cmd.Process.Pid)
            syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
        }
    }()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    var result string
    if err != nil {
        result = stderr.String()
    } else {
        result = stdout.String()
    }
}
```

Comment: edit, please check, I want to know why write waitDone here, It seems `waitDone ` useless.

Comment: See the edit to the answer. The waitDone channel is not needed because the context is guaranteed to complete within the scope of the function. If the timeout is specified through a context argument (as it should be), then waitDone is needed to ensure that the goroutine exits.

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the channel when your `ExecCommand` function exits.
Since you are sending a message in a goroutine, there is no guarantee it will be sent before the function exits. In fact, all times I ran, it happened after.
Your test will work fine without the first deferable.

```
    defer func() {
        log.Printf("waitDone addr:%v\n", &waitDone)
        log.Printf("close waitdone channel\n")
        close(waitDone) // <- here 
    }()

    go func() {
        err = cmd.Run()
        log.Printf("waitDone addr:%v\n", &waitDone)
        waitDone <- struct{}{}  // <- and here
    }()
```

Update: 
@Cerise-Limón pointed out you could use the context in the `cmd` call. 
Since you are already using a timeout context, this will fit perfeclty

```
cmd = exec.CommandContext(ctx, "bash", "-c", "--", command)
// cmd = exec.Command("bash", "-c", "--", command)
```

This could save you from using this complicated logic to check for a timeout.

Comment: add comment, please check. And I still have question, imho, i use select cases, It should be block right?